# Celery tasks through view (Django) returned as pending, but okay via Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-task, django-1.11

This issue has been discussed before and looking over numerous posts, I am so far unable to find a solution to this problem. I'm new to celery so my learning curve is still fairly steep. Below my current scripts:

**myapp.__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery_main import app as celery_app # Ensures app is always imported when Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**myapp.celery_main.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps

# Initialise the app
app = Celery()                          
app.config_from_object('myapp.celeryconfig')  # WORKS WHEN CALLED THROUGH VIEW/DJANGO: Tell Celery instance to use celeryconfig module
#app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')  # WORKS WHEN CALLED THROUGH TERMINAL

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

**myapp.celeryconfig.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from datetime import timedelta

## List of modules to import when celery starts.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('celery_tasks',)

## Message Broker (RabbitMQ) settings.
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
BROKER_PORT = 5672

## Result store settings.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'

## Misc
#CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'doctor-every-10-seconds': {
        'task': 'celery_tasks.fav_doctor',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3),
    },
}
```

**myapp.celery_tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery.task import task

suf = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n, {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}.get(n if n < 20 else n % 10, "th"))
@task
def fav_doctor():
    # Stuff happend here

@task
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]

@task
def send_email(user_id):
    # Stuff happend here

@task
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

**anotherapp.settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'kombu.transport.django',
]
```

**myapp.views.admin_scripts.py**

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from myapp.celery_tasks import fav_doctor, reverse, send_email, add
from myapp.celery_main import app

@login_required
def admin_script_dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Admin_Script(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                # Results
                async_result = add.delay(2, 5)
                task_id = async_result.task_id
                res = AsyncResult(async_result)
                res_1 = add.AsyncResult(async_result)
                res_2 = add.AsyncResult(async_result.id)
                print ("async_result: {0}\ntask_id: {1}\nres: {2}\nres_1: {3}\nres_2: {4}".format(async_result, task_id, res, res_1, res_2))

                # Backend: Make sure the client is configured with the right backend
                print("Backend check: {0}".format(async_result.backend))

                # States/statuses
                task_state = res.state
                A = async_result.status
                B = res.status
                print ("task_state: {0}\nA: {1}\nB: {2}".format(task_state, A, B))
```

The results when triggering the celery workers through my django application (related to the print statements in `app.views.admin_scripts.py`):

```
async_result: 00d7ec84-ebdb-4968-9ea6-f20ca2a793b7
task_id: 00d7ec84-ebdb-4968-9ea6-f20ca2a793b7
res: 00d7ec84-ebdb-4968-9ea6-f20ca2a793b7
res_1: 00d7ec84-ebdb-4968-9ea6-f20ca2a793b7
res_2: 00d7ec84-ebdb-4968-9ea6-f20ca2a793b7
Backend check: <celery.backends.rpc.RPCBackend object at 0x106e308d0>
task_state: PENDING
A: PENDING
B: PENDING
```

Output in Terminal triggered:

```
[2018-07-15 21:41:47,015: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'MyApp.celery_tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see <link> for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'task': 'MyApp.celery_tasks.add', 'id': 'b21ffa43-d1f1-4767-9ab8-e58afec3ea0f', 'args': [2, 5], 'kwargs': {}, 'retries': 0, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'utc': True, 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'taskset': None, 'chord': None} (266b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/My_MBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 465, in on_task_received
    strategies[type_](message, body,
KeyError: 'MyApp.celery_tasks.add'
```

I have several questions:

**1.** I can trigger the expected results by using commands in Terminal:

```
celery -A celery_tasks worker -l info
```

Then in the Python shell:

```
from celery_tasks import *
add.delay(2,3)
```

Which succeeds:

```
[2018-07-13 10:12:14,943: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery_tasks.add[c100ad91-2f94-40b1-bb0e-9bc2990ff3bc]
[2018-07-13 10:12:14,961: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery_tasks.add[c100ad91-2f94-40b1-bb0e-9bc2990ff3bc] succeeded in 0.017578680999577045s: 54
```

So executing the tasks in Terminal works, but not in my `view.py` in Django, why not?

**2.** Perhaps related to **1.**: I have to, annoyingly, configure in `app.celery_main.py` the `app.config_from_object` depending if I want to test via Django, or via Terminal. You can see either I set the `celeryconfig.py` with myapp name prefixed, or without. Otherwise, an error message is thrown. I suspect some kind of import looping is causing an issue here (though I could be wrong) but I don't know why/where. How can I overcome this?

**3.** In my `settings.py` file (not `celeryconfig.py`) I have configured in `INSTALLED_APPS: 'kombu.transport.django'`. Is this necessary? I'm using **celery 3.1.26.post2 (Cipater)**

**4.** In all my files I have at the top:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

For what purpose is this for exactly and for 3.1.26 is it required?

**5.** I read [here](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#result-backend-doesn-t-work-or-tasks-are-always-in-pending-state), that you need to ensure the client is configured with the right backend. But I'm not sure exactly what this means. My print out is (as per `app.views.admin_scripts.py`):

```
Backend check: <celery.backends.rpc.RPCBackend object at 0x106e308d0>
```

If there are any abnormalities in my code you recognise, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still trying to figure out the answer to my question 2, meanwhile I've figured out how to retrieve the required results: I have `async_result = add.delay(2, 5)` *but then after this* I need to have `async_result.get()` followed by `task_output = async_result.result`. The result status/state (`async_result.state` or `async_result.status`) is then set to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Celery tasks should [have proper names](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names). When running from django, the task name is `MyApp.celery_tasks.add` which is why celery worker not able to run it. But from terminal when your imported using `from celery_tasks import *`, task name is `celery_tasks.add` which is why it is working correctly.
2. You can change config based on environment variable.
3. `kombu.transport.django` Adding this not necessary.
4. This is related to Python 2/3. See [this docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html#from-future-import-unicode-literals) for more info.
5. If you want task results after the task is completed, it should be stored somewhere. So backend is needed for this. If you don't want to retrieve results, you don't need this.

Comment: ChillarAnand: thank you for the reply. The main question is Qu1, I tried out the naming convention i.e. `@task(name='celery_tasks.add')` and then in my view.py `async_result = celery_tasks.add.delay(2, 5)` but I still get the same results. I can't think where else the code could be potentially wrong. Maybe I need to restructure and place all celery-related files in its own app, upgrade to version 4,...

Comment: I also upgraded to celery 4.2.0, still no solution.